# Cannot see requests in Jaeger UI

Tags: node.js, open-telemetry, jaeger

I am trying to see my requests in Jaeger UI. I am using OTLPTraceExporter but it does not working. I can see the requests in the console but not in Jaeger UI. I am importing init function in index.js and use it. What's wrong?

```
"use strict";

const {
  BasicTracerProvider,
  ConsoleSpanExporter,
  SimpleSpanProcessor,
  BatchSpanProcessor,
} = require("@opentelemetry/tracing");
const { CollectorTraceExporter } = require("@opentelemetry/exporter-collector");
const { Resource } = require("@opentelemetry/resources");
const {
  SemanticResourceAttributes,
} = require("@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions");
const {
  ExpressInstrumentation,
} = require("@opentelemetry/instrumentation-express");
const { HttpInstrumentation } = require("@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http");
const { registerInstrumentations } = require("@opentelemetry/instrumentation");
const opentelemetry = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-node");
const {
  getNodeAutoInstrumentations,
} = require("@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node");
const { JaegerExporter } = require("@opentelemetry/exporter-jaeger");
const { NodeTracerProvider } = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node");
const { OTTracePropagator } = require("@opentelemetry/propagator-ot-trace");
const {
  OTLPTraceExporter,
} = require("@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-proto");

const init = (serviceName, environment) => {
  // User Collector Or Jaeger Exporter
  //const exporter = new CollectorTraceExporter(options)

  const exporter = new OTLPTraceExporter({
    url: "http://localhost:4318/v1/traces",
  }); //* JaegerExported is deprecated

  const provider = new NodeTracerProvider({
    resource: new Resource({
      [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: serviceName, // Service name that showuld be listed in jaeger ui
      [SemanticResourceAttributes.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT]: environment,
    }),
  });

  provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter));

  // Use the BatchSpanProcessor to export spans in batches in order to more efficiently use resources.
  provider.addSpanProcessor(new BatchSpanProcessor(exporter));

  // Enable to see the spans printed in the console by the ConsoleSpanExporter
  provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter()));

  provider.register({ propagator: new OTTracePropagator() });

  console.log("tracing initialized");

  registerInstrumentations({
    instrumentations: [new ExpressInstrumentation(), new HttpInstrumentation()],
  });

  const tracer = provider.getTracer(serviceName);
  return { tracer };
};

module.exports = {
  init: init,
};
```

I tried using JaegerExporter and I could see requests in Jaeger UI but it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try without `v1/traces`:

```
  const exporter = new OTLPTraceExporter({
    url: "http://localhost:4318/",
  });
```

Have you followed any official documentation that led you to your code? Please point to it so we could fix it if it's incorrect.

Side note: Why are you using OTPropagator instead of W3C? OTPropagator is a very weird, niche format.

Comment: Actually, I was trying different things in the hope of seeing requests in Jaeger UI so it is a bit messy.  In other words, I was not following any particular documentation. Thanks for the side note. Moreover, thanks for answering.